# Fiware IDM-Keyrock: How to check if user has some permission(permission_fiware) using keyrock API

Tags: fiware

I created some permissions(permission_fiware table) in Horizon regarding urls that can or cant be seen.I created permission(name:Upload images, with resource: "/image_upload") and role(role_fiware) admin that has this permission.
Now i want to check whether some user that is logged in to my application can view that page on url "/image_upload" that i defined in horizons permission.So my guess is i should first check what roles user has, and after that whether those roles that user is assigned have required permission.
So, my question is next:
How can i list what permission one specific user has.
In Keyrocks API:

http://docs.keyrock.apiary.io/#reference/keystone-extensions/role-user-relationships/list-users-role-assignments

i found how i can list all permissions for a specific role

```
http://keyrock/OS-ROLES/roles/role_id/permissions
```

but how can i get information about what roles(role_fiware) are assigned to a user?

Answer (score 2):

As stands in the [FIWARE-IDM documentation](http://fiware-idm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user_guide.html#get-authenticated-user) doing a request against the resource `user` of your IDM host using the `access_token`, will return the user information, and within that information you will find the roles that user have assigned:

```
GET
/user?access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX


Response:

{
  "organizations": [{
    "website": "",
    "city": "",
    "name": "Franchise1",
    "img": "/static/dashboard/img/logos/small/group.png",
    "domain_id": "default",
    "enabled": true,
    "id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "roles": [{
      "name": "Franchise manager",
      "id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    }],
    "email": "",
    "description": "Test Organization"
  }],
  "displayName": "user1",
  "roles": [{
    "name": "End user",
    "id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  }],
  "app_id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "email": "user1@test.com",
  "id": "user1"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i wanted to know if there is a way(API) for some privileged user to see what roles some other user has.